# How to get total messages sent/received per user in ejabberd?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to get total messages received/sent per user in ejabberd server + also in MUC. Can i get this info in ejabberdctl command ? Or any module available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not have that info available. You would have to write a custom module register the hook you would like to track, for example user_send_packet, user_receive_packet. See for reference: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/

From that custom plugin, you can perform the storage and calculation you want.

Note that counting per user on a large server will be very consuming.